# I found Error while updating data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

MongoError: After applying the update to the document

```
{_id: ObjectId('5a02f5aac293238265959fd7') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('5a02f7cdc0d5868391967dd5')
```

Comment: you can find your document with _id and update the other keys if you want to update. to update other keys you dont need to send the _id again. if you need any more info please post your full query

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the `_id` value. If you want to change it, then it means that you need to create a new document and delete the old one.